# Outbound proxy with multiple public IPs in Azure

Tags: azure, email-server, haproxy

For services where the outgoing (client) public IP address is important, such as email delivery - an HAProxy setup is often used to host the IPs, with MTAs driving the IP selection via Proxy Protocol.

Making the proxy layer resilient is usually done via `keepalived`. In public clouds this needs to be done differently, e.g. [AWS](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-on-aws-best-practices-part-3).

Public clouds also have limitations on numbers of IPs per node (or per NIC).

Does Azure have "outbound proxy as-a-service", and can it host hundreds of IPs?

Failing that, are there practices to follow for a resilient HAProxy outbound cluster in Azure, akin to the AWS example above?

Comment: It depends on your requirements, do you need it to be multi region? Do you need backup and restore? How much capacity do you need?

Comment: It will be multi-region, but each region can be separate from a resilience point of view.
Backup & restore is not that important, as we can hold all config in a tool like Ansible. Capacity - each region will be sending about 1GiB/s at peak.

Answer (score 1):

There is a NAT gateway
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nat-gateway/nat-overview

Azure NAT Gateway is a fully managed and highly resilient Network Address Translation (NAT) service. You can use Azure NAT Gateway to let all instances in a private subnet connect outbound to the internet while remaining fully private. Unsolicited inbound connections from the internet aren't permitted through a NAT gateway. Only packets arriving as response packets to an outbound connection can pass through a NAT gateway.

Comment: Thank you. NAT is OK, but it has the disadvantage of having to manage inside & outside IP ranges and the mappings between. Proxy protocol is more usable as the originating MTA knows which public IP it wants the proxy to use (and passes it in the proxy header).

Comment: No that's not needed. Outbound NAT is something different. You only need to deploy the NAT Gateway and link to a vnet/subnet and that's it. You can even associate a public ip range as outbound ips and the NAT gateway will allocate that himself. Please check the docs

Comment: However the internal nodes will connect to the inside addresses, so any reporting they provide etc. is not public-IP aware?

Comment: What do you mean with nodes? VM's?

Comment: By the way regarding email delivery in Azure, Microsoft has partner up with SendGrid, so for outgoing email you can use that service.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I should have said "hosts". SendGrid has its place, but we'd like to use our own delivery IPs (BYOIP).